# Show variable inside text field label

Tags: xcode, cocoa, label, textfield, nstextfield

In my Cocoa application I show the result of a calculation in a NSTextView, now I wish you could see the result in a NSextField, I tried in every way but did not succeed.

```
[textField insertText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i \n", giorni]];
```

Comment: What is the value of giorni? Have you looked at it in the debugger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about: (edited for the NS instead of UI textField)

```
[textField setIntValue:giorni];
```

Comment: I had already tried, but he gives me error: No visible@interface for 'NStextField' declares the selector 'setText'.

Comment: Updated answer to reflect that it is a NSTextField